# Why does my O(1) space code use up more memory than my O(logN) space code, provided there are no large constants in the O(1) expression?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management

I am currently brushing up on my Java skills, and am confused about how some of the code I have written is executing on a low level. This is for a Leetcode question called "Deepest Leaves Sum" where the goal is to find the sum of the leaves at the deepest level.

My first attempt at the problem was as such:

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode() {}
 *     TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
 *         this.val = val;
 *         this.left = left;
 *         this.right = right;
 *     }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    private int maxDepth;
    public int deepestLeavesSum(TreeNode root) {
        /*
          Algorithm:
          Perform a depth-first search, keeping track of depth
          use a global Integer to keep track of the max level
          Use a hashmap of <level, sum> to keep track of the max depth
          At the end, recall hashmap's sum at max depth

         O(N) time, O(logN) space.
        */
      HashMap<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
      maxDepth = 1; // Root
      dfs(root, 1, map);
      return map.get(maxDepth);
    }
  
    private void dfs(TreeNode root, int level, HashMap<Integer,Integer> map){
      map.put(level, map.getOrDefault(level, 0) + root.val);
      if(root.left != null)
        dfs(root.left, level+1, map);
      if(root.right != null)
        dfs(root.right, level+1, map);
      maxDepth = Math.max(level, maxDepth);
    }
}
```

The above code took 2ms to pass all 15 of the tests, and 39.4 MB of space. I refactored the above code into a version that uses the same logic, but constant space, as shown here:

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode() {}
 *     TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
 *         this.val = val;
 *         this.left = left;
 *         this.right = right;
 *     }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    private int maxDepth;
    private int maxSum;
    public int deepestLeavesSum(TreeNode root) {
        /*
          Optimized Algorithm:
          Perform a depth-first search, keeping track of depth
          use a global Integer to keep track of the max level
          Use an int as well to keep track of the sum at max depth
          
          O(N) time, O(1) space
        */
      maxDepth = 1; // Root
      maxSum = 0;
      dfs(root, 1);
      return maxSum;
    }
  
    private void dfs(TreeNode root, int level){
      if(maxDepth == level)
        maxSum+=root.val;
      else if (level > maxDepth){
        maxSum = root.val;
        maxDepth = level;
      }
      
      if(root.left != null)
        dfs(root.left, level+1);
      if(root.right != null)
        dfs(root.right, level+1);
    }
}
```

In this above sample, the code ran quicker (~0 ms) but used up 40.6 MB of space for all 15 tests.

I understand that this is really marginal stuff, and 15 tests is hardly an asymptotic bound. Despite this, I would have to imagine that the overhead of 2 integers per test (maxSum, maxDepth) would be less than a HashMap or large int[] lookup table (which performed somewhere in between these two, with regards to speed and memory).

Why would this be? It seems that as I intend to reduce the memory used, my speed goes up (I would assume due to caching/locality) but my actual memory use increases instead of decreases.

Comment: how have you measured space and got that numbers?

Comment: I did not manually measure space. If all 15 tests pass, the Leetcode website reports back the total execution time and memory usage. From a Google search, most answers are speculative on the exact details on how Leetcode does this.

Comment: It may happen that in the longer run the garbage collector got rid of something completely unrelated, while in case of the faster code it simply did not have time to do that.